# bash script stdout creates file before running

Tags: bash, stdout

I'm creating some scripts. I'll leave out the cron, file change logs, etc.

The part of the script that is a problem is below:

`#! /bin/bash
ls>./directoryContents.txt`

If you run this script you will find directoryContents.txt as one of the files listed by ls.

Why is the file directoryContents.txt created before the running of the ls command?

Is there a simple way to get around this?

Comment: which operating system you running this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to get around this?

To get around this just grep it out.

```
ls | grep -v directoryContents.txt >./directoryContents.txt
```

This also works with multiple calls.

Comment: Awesome and simple. I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 5):

When you use `command > file`, the shell creates, truncates and opens the file before running the command.

A simple way to avoid listing this file would be just to create it elsewhere and then move it into the directory afterwards:

```
ls > /tmp/directoryContents.txt && mv /tmp/directoryContents.txt directoryContents.txt
```

Of course this would only work once.

Better would be to use an extended glob in Bash to match everything except the file:

```
shopt -s extglob
printf '%s\n' !(directoryContents.txt) > directoryContents.txt
```

Comment: So it does open the file before the command. Thanks for the input. Also, I may use this stuff in the future.  The glob idea is good.

Comment: @Paultheawesome13 This sequence of events is a common source of trouble for beginning shell users. For instance, if you try to have a command read from a file, process it, and send output to the same file, you'll find that the file's contents get deleted ("truncated") before it's read. The temp file trick is a possible workaround for this as well.